# If else on text element

Tags: php

Hello would appreciate any help having problems with this code.

```
       value="<?phpif($_GET['level']== "Grade 2"){ echo "Grade 3";}?>"
```

My idea is having an if else on this text element so it may check the level of the student and once its checks it should progress the student by a certain level so far i have this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\enrollpage.php on line 212

Also i have this problem, It cannot retrieve $_GET['level'] i tried using get to retrieve from this from and post from the previous from but still not working.

Comment: Add a space between php and if

Comment: I would recommend to use some php editor like nodepad++ , netbeans or eclipse, which will automatically figure out the wrong syntax like space missing etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space between `<?php` and your first statement:

```
<?php if($_GET['level']== "Grade 2"){ echo "Grade 3";}?>
```

Comment: Thank you. found it just now too.

Answer (score 1):

```
  value="<?php if($_GET['level'] == 'Grade 2'){ echo 'Grade 3';} ?>"
```